# IdentityServer4 endless redirect after login

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to setup IdentityServer4 for the first time, and am following the steps in the docs for adding a JS client. I must have something configured incorrectly, but I can't figure out what it is. The flow is as follows:

1. User hits "login" on Client A
2. Client A sends login request to IS4 (upon debugging, the "returnUrl" parameter seems correct)
3. using the IS4 extension method I am signing the user in (HttpContext.SignInAsync)
4. user is redirected to "connect/authorize/callback" which redirects them to the login method again and the circular reference continues until the browser stops it and throws error.

Relevant code:

startup.cs

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UsersContext>(o =>
                o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersRuntime")));
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            services.AddIdentityServer(o =>
                {
                })
                .AddTestUsers(Identity.Users.Get())
                .AddConfigurationStore(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersRuntime"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersRuntime"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            InitializeDatabase(app);
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseHttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHttpStatusCodeExceptionMiddleware();
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            if (env.IsProduction())
            {
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health");
            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Users API");
                c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });
        }

    private void InitializeDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UsersContext>().Database.Migrate();
                var persistedGrantDbContext =
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PersistedGrantDbContext>();
                persistedGrantDbContext.Database.Migrate();
                var configDb = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationDbContext>();
                configDb.Database.Migrate();
                var testClient = new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "TestClient",
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms = new List<string>{SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256},
                    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = (int)TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                    AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.PersistedGrantTypes.AuthorizationCode
                    },
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "Read",
                        "Write"
                    },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>
                    {
                      "https://localhost:5003"  
                    },
                    RedirectUris = new List<string>{"https://localhost:5003/callback.html"}
                };
                configDb.Clients.Add(testClient.ToEntity());
                configDb.SaveChanges();
                var resource = new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "TestApi",
                    ShowInDiscoveryDocument = true,
                    AllowedAccessTokenSigningAlgorithms = new List<string>{SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256},
                    Scopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "Read",
                        "Write"
                        
                    }
                };
                configDb.ApiResources.Add(resource.ToEntity());
                var readScope = new ApiScope("Read");
                var writeScope = new ApiScope("Write");
                configDb.ApiScopes.AddRange(new []{readScope.ToEntity(), writeScope.ToEntity()});
                configDb.SaveChanges();
                
            }
        }
```

login controller

```cs
    [Route("account/login")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginControllerOidc: ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string returnUrl)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(new IdentityServerUser("Test")
            {
                DisplayName = "Test Display Name",
                
                AdditionalClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("additionalClaim", "claimValue")
                }
            });
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

config for oidc-client.js

```cs
var config = {
    authority: "https://localhost:5001",
    client_id: "TestClient",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope:"Read Write",
    post_logout_redirect_uri : "https://localhost:5003/index.html"
};
```

[Redirect Issue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVlZT.png)

I'm at a loss for what it left to do. Following the docs I think I have everything setup correctly. Guides I am following can be found [Here (adding javascript client)](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html) and [Here (sign in)](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html)

The cookie is being set correctly (I think) as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBNs0.png)

Comment: can you confirm your ssl dev certificate is setup properly? Here is a manual to setup https://github.com/nahidf/auth0-adventures#local-https-with-aspnet-core - Also try to delete all cookies and re-launch the apps with https

Comment: SSL is setup and being used locally. I have cleared all of the cookies and restarted the apps multiple times. Still coming back to the redirect loop.

Comment: here is a good post: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Help-Im-Stuck-in-a-Redirect-Loop

Comment: yeah, I had already tried those solutions. I found the issue, and answered below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I was having was due to the `subjectId` in the controller not matching a `subjectId` in the TestUsers.